# python webkitgtk xmlhttprequest file protocol

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, xmlhttprequest, file-uri

How to enable xmlhttprequest for file:// protocol in pywebkit ?

just like chrome does

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=171316324d16747b&hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `enable-file-access-from-file-uris` property on `WebView`:

```
view = webkit.WebView()
settings = view.get_settings()
settings.set_property('enable-file-access-from-file-uris', 1)
view.open('file://./foo.html')
```

Example file `foo.html` which writes contents of `file://./bar.html` into the body:

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script></head>
<body><script>
$.ajax({url: 'file://./bar.html', success: function(data) {
    document.write(data);
    }
});
</script></body></html>
```